# Block brute force attacks on exim2

Tags: linux, exim

Suddenly some people or computers are trying to log in on my linux directadmin server.

The last days I receive a lot of messages of brute force attacks for Exim2 in Direct Admin.

I have already installed Fail2Ban & Block_IP.SH is on the server.

So if the user fails 15 times login then the ip address will be blocked.

How can I stop the attacks from continuing, so the computers will not try to login any more?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This a poorly written distributed bot.  As far as I can tell these hosts are trying to authenticate over an unencrypted connection.  If you require a secure connection to authenticate, they will fail even.  However, it appears you are allowing authentication on unencrypted connections.

By default `fail2ban` will miss this condition, but blocks after 3 attempts in 10 minutes. You can create a `jail.local` file to adjust the number of failures required to get banned by `fail2ban` or increase the ban time.  `fail2ban-client` also allows you to adjust the configuration while the server is running. You may need to create a `exim.local` file in `filter.d` to match the lines that are being generated.  I have included the contents of my `exim.local`.  You can use `fail2ban-regex` to test regex (you will need to replace python includes in the regex).

```
[Definition]

host_info = H=([\w.-]+ )?(\(\S+\) )?\[<HOST>\](:\d+)? ?(I=\[\S+\]:\d+ )?(U=\S+ )?(P=e?smtp )?

failregex = ^%(pid)s %(host_info)s [^:]+: Sender host address is listed in zen.spamhaus.org
        ^%(pid)s %(host_info)s sender verify fail for <\S+>: (?:Unknown user|Unrouteable address|all relevant MX records point to non-existent hosts)\s*$
        ^%(pid)s (plain|login) authenticator failed for (\S+ )?\(\S+\) \[<HOST>\]: 535 Incorrect authentication data( \(set_id=.*\)|: \d+ Time\(s\))?\s*$
        ^%(pid)s %(host_info)s F=(<>|[^@]+@\S+) rejected RCPT [^@]+@\S+: (relay not permitted|Sender verify failed|Unknown user)\s*$
        ^%(pid)s SMTP protocol synchronization error \([^)]*\): rejected (connection from|"\S+") %(host_info)s(next )?input=".*"\s*$
        ^%(pid)s SMTP call from \S+ \[<HOST>\](:\d+)? (I=\[\S+\]:\d+ )?dropped: too many nonmail commands \(last was "\S+"\)\s*$
        \[<HOST>\]: 535 Incorrect authentication data
        ^%(pid)s %(host_info)s Warning: smtp used a hostname$
        ^%(pid)s no MAIL in SMTP connection from (\([^)]+\) )?\[<HOST>\] D=\d+(m\d+)?s( C=.*)?$
        ^%(pid)s SMTP protocol synchronization error \(input sent without waiting for greeting\): rejected connection from %(host_info)s

ignoreregex =
```